# How to calculate year old date range from the current date(EDT) in xslt 1.0

Tags: datetime, xslt

Could some one please suggest me out to calculate 1 year back old date time from the current date time which is in EDT format using XSLT 1.0.

I know using xslt 2.0 there are function like 'yearMonthDuration' but need to perform this in xslt 1.0.

I have this
'''
2021-09-21
11:14:20 EDT
'''
I need to get as **2020**0921111420 EDT. This is the format I will need to convert as shown YYYYMMDDTTMMSS EDT

Please help in this regard.

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor do you intend to use? And how do you get the current date (XSLT 1.0 does not support this). And what exactly does "year old date range" mean? Please edit your question and show the exact result you expect to get.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I extract year column and add 365 to this will that work?

If all you want to do is add 1 year to a given date, you could start by extracting the year component and simply adding 1 to it, leaving the month and day components as they are. However, this will produce an invalid date if the given date is February 29 in a leap year. Still, it's rather simple to correct for that - say something like:

```
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($given-date, 1, 4) + 1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="md" select="substring($given-date, 5, 10)" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$md='-02-29'">-02-28</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$md"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

---

**Added:**

> I have this ''' 2021-09-21 11:14:20 EDT ''' I need to get as 20200921111420 EDT

That's equally simple:

```
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($given-date, 1, 4) - 1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="mdt" select="translate(substring($given-date, 6, 14), '-: ', '')" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="starts-with($mdt, '0229')">
            <xsl:text>0228</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($mdt, 5)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$mdt"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($given-date, 20)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

EXSLT.Date has some support e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs date">

  <xsl:template match="date">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' - ', date:add(., 'P1Y'))"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives `<date>2021-09-22 - 2022-09-22</date>` for an input of e.g. `<date>2021-09-22</date>`.

So check whether you use processor supporting that or can use an extension to your XSLT processor, for .NET XslCompiledTransform there is one with https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mvp.Xml.NetStandard/.